# Error post AJAX from Spring JAVA

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I already created MVC spring and I want consume with SAPUI5 (javascript) with AJAX but I found an error "415 (Unsupported Media Type)". I use swagger in spring for test CRUD. in swagger, I success for insert data but failed in AJAX.

controller Spring:

```
@PostMapping(value={"/tesinsert"}, consumes={"application/json"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public ResponseEntity<?> insert(@RequestBody KasusEntity user) throws Exception {
    Map result = new HashMap();
    userService.insertTabel(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

in javascript:

```
        var data = {
                "kodekasus":5,
                "nama":"baru",
                "isdelete":1,
                "createdby":"hahaa",
                "createddate":null,
                "updatedby":"hihii",
                "updateddate":null
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data, 
            success: function(data) { 
                console.log('sukses: '+data); 
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log('gagal: '+error);
            }
        });
```

if I code above in AJAX, show error "415 (Unsupported Media Type)", if I add in AJAX show different error: "Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403
":

```
        headers: {
            Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            }
```

How to solve this problem? 
Thanks.
Bobby

Answer (score 0):

Add `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data, 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) { 
                console.log('sukses: '+data); 
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log('gagal: '+error);
            }
        });
```